# Positioning fixed element within an iframe depending on parent window scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, sticky

**Goal:** I'm trying to accomplish to have a sticky element in an iframe positioned at the bottom of the browser window - until it hits the bottom of the iframe window, then, when scrolling further down on the parent page the element stays put, and if one is scrolling up again the element positions itself at the bottom of the browser window again.

Without the iframe a simple solution (and a showcase of what I want to achieve) would be like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/30a1sxk9/2/

My page containing this iframe looks roughly like this:
https://jsfiddle.net/q9m1h2j5/1/

-> since the scrolling is happening outside the iframe the fixed position is always at the bottom.

I'm looking for a robust and performant solution to position this element (with proper boundaries) in the iframe from **WITHIN the iframe**.
My main problem is that I have no access to the surrounding page - except via JavaScript from within the iframe (Cross origin should not make problems since the container and the iframe have the same domain)
So I can't guarantee what is outside of my iframe, but have to take it into account for determining the position of element. I also can't change the general setup of my page.

**My approach would be something like this, inside the iframe:**

```
let $footer = $('.sticky-footer');

window.parent.onscroll = function() {
  let footerPos = this.scrollY + this.innerHeight - 60;

    console.debug('onScroll: ', footerPos);
  $footer.css({
    position: 'absolute',
    top: footerPos + 'px'
  })
};
```

where I put an onscroll listener on the window.parent and calculating and setting the absolute position of the element each event call.

but I'm having trouble figuring out how to calculate the exact absolute position where the sticky-footer is supposed to be and the boundaries where it is allowed to move. 
I'd have to determine the exact Y top position of the iframe and the bottom position - is this somehow reliably possible?

Also I'm not sure if setting the absolute position like this is a very good approach - since after first prototyping I noticed some jittering when scrolling fast
- so maybe CSS transformations would be better? or is there a different way to achieve this?

Any help, solutions and hints are very much appreciated!

Comment: Having the same problem. Did you find any solution?

Comment: No, sadly I didn't yet, and the feature request for which I needed it is on hold right now.

Comment: doable, for communication between parent and child frame use `postMessage()` and as you cannot actually hook on `window.parent.onscroll` as you posted, you need to post scroll position to iframe via the messages and then absolutely position your element using received values